# Archaius не читает обновленные значения из properties файла

Tags: java, archaius

`config.properties`:

```
microservices.archaius.properties.one=one-value
```

`Main` class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

`Controller` class:

```java
@RestController
public class ConfigPropertiesController {

    private static final String DEFAULT_NOT_FOUND_PROPERTY_MESSAGE = "not found!";

    private DynamicStringProperty defaultProperty;

    @PostConstruct
    private void setUp() {
        defaultProperty = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance()
            .getStringProperty("microservices.archaius.properties.one",
                DEFAULT_NOT_FOUND_PROPERTY_MESSAGE);
    }

    @GetMapping("/default")
    public String defaultPropertyValue() {
        return String.format("Property name: %s\nProperty value: %s", defaultProperty.getName(),
            defaultProperty.get());
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Выполняю последовательность действий:

1. Отправляю запрос `GET localhost:8080/default` и в ответ:

```json
Property name: microservices.archaius.properties.one
Property value: one-value
```

2. Меняю `config.properties`:

```
microservices.archaius.properties.one=UPDATED VALUE
```

3. Опять отправляю запрос `GET localhost:8080/default` и в ответ получаю **старые значения**:

```json
Property name: microservices.archaius.properties.one
Property value: one-value
```

Archaius не читает обновленные значения из `config.properties` файла?

Comment: Где находится файл, в котором производятся изменения?

Comment: @NowhereMan,  файл находится в каталоге `/resources/`, который находится внутри проекта и полный путь выгляди так: `/resources/application.properties`